# AWS Aurora's PostgreSQL equivalent to AWS Aurora's MySQL "@@aurora_server_id"

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to check whether or not I'm connected to a specific reader instance in AWS Aurora's PostgreSQL server. When I was doing this in MySQL I was able to use `SELECT @@aurora_server_id` to check if I was connected to let's say reader#3 instead of reader#2. I was wondering if there was a function in PostgreSQL that I could use. I found that `SELECT * FROM aurora_replica_status()` can be used to see which one is the writer instance but not the one you are currently connected to.

Thanks!